# Iterating over a List<Tuple> inside hashmap in java

Tags: java, list, hashmap, tuples

I have stored a key-value pair in the hash map where key is a string ID and value is List of tuple .I need to fetch the data present in the list and insert into Database. What is the code logic to iterate over the List of tuple inside a map and get the data from the list?

Comment: `Map.values()` gives you a `Collection` of `List<Tuple>`. If you've already known how to iterate over a `Collection` and a `List`, this should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the values from map using map.values method or you can use Entry if you need to add some conditions based on keys.

```
Map<String, List<Tuple>> data = somemethod();

for(List<Tuple> tuples : data.values()) {
   //... some code
}
```

or

```
for(Map.Entry<String, List<Tuple>> entry : data.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    List<Tuple> tuples = entry.getValue();
    // ... Some code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways is using `Java 8 streams`

```
map.values() // get all the list of tuples i.e. values
    .stream() // java 8 stream api
    .flatMap(listOfTuple -> listOfTuple.stream()) // flattening the list
    .forEach(tuple -> doWhatEverWithTuple(tuple)); // use individual tuple
```

Comment: I tried to iterate my list this way. below is my code:.                   map.values()
    .stream()
    .flatMap(listOfTuple -> listOfTuple.stream())
    .forEach(tuple -> repository.saveAllRows(tuple));               And this is my repository code:.             @Query(value="insert into student").      public void saveAllRows(Tuple tuple);. I need to store the tuple data in the SQL table. But i'm getting error in the method saveAllRows. Can you tell if I'm wrong somewhere?

Comment: @SonalMishra if `saveAllRows` defined with `throws Exception` then it will give error.
You can use try catch in the forEach and handle the exception there